# updating Nuget package , refreshes the DTO with runtime error

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

My project uses some reference of other project which we consume using nuget packages, application is reflecting the new properties I added , I'm able to set the properties and build the solution successfully. During execution i get an error this error -

> method not found: 'void   DTO.Objects.Lead.set_ReferralCompany(System.String)'

It seems as if during run time it is unable to set  value to property. I tried deleting nuget cache, package folder, reinstalling packages and uninstall and re-install , but nothing solved my issue

```
        public string ReferralCompany
        {
            get { return _referralCompany; }
            set
            {
                _referralCompany = value;
                AddChange(nameof(ReferralCompany), 
                _referralCompany.ToString());
            }
        }
        internal void AddChange(string key, string value)
        {
            if (_changeTrackingActive)
            {
                if (Changes == null)
                {
                    Changes = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                }

                if (Changes.Any(entry => entry.Key == key))
                {
                    Changes[key] = value;
                }
                else
                {
                    Changes.Add(key, value);
                }
            }
        }
```

During run time it should not throw this error:

> method not found:  'DTO.Objects.Lead.set_ReferralCompany(System.String)

Comment: Are you using the same a reference to that nuget package in multi-projects inside the same solution?

Comment: yes, we have multiple projects consuming the same dto

Comment: If it is so, try to manage the nugets in the solution and check the Consolidate tab. Maybe a project is using an older version of the library?

Comment: Yes, if you do not have the consolidate tab, just check if all projects are using the same nuget version.

Comment: I verified that all of them are consuming the new version only , not sure y is it creating a problem at run time(while executing the code). I also verified that all the DTO as referring to the lastest version , but still no luck :(

Comment: Is it possible somehow to have an old version of the dll inside the GAC? Or in the bin folder?

Comment: Check the assembly in the bin output directory if that is really the assembly you would expect. Is there maybe a transitive dependency referencing the other version?